# UIMA RUTA - How to combine annotations?

Tags: java, annotations, uima, ruta

I built some custom annotations on sample phrases in order to recognize keywords. The problem that I have right now is that I can't combine these annotations to build upper-level patterns of annotations.

eg. the phrases are:
1."I want to buy eggs."
2."I want to have breakfast with bread."
3."I want to have eggs for breakfast."

```
DECLARE Annotation Eggs;
Entity{FEATURE("text","eggs")->MARK(Eggs)};

DECLARE Annotation Breakfast;
Entity{FEATURE("text","breakfast")->MARK(Breakfast)};
```

How could I build a new annotation, which combines/merge the two annotations already built and recognize the third phrase?
I have tried the type below already but it's not working:

```
DECLARE Annotation EggsForBreakfast;
Entity{AND(CONTAINS(Eggs),CONTAINS(Breakfast))->MARK(EggsForBreakfast)};
```

Comment: The CONTAINS in your last rule checks if there are these annoations within the matches one, which is Entity. You need rather something like: `Document{CONTAINS(Eggs),CONTAINS(Breakfast)->MARK(EggsForBreakfast)};`

Answer (score 2):

The CONTAINS in your last rule checks if there are these annotations within the matches one, which is Entity. You need rather something like:

```
Document{CONTAINS(Eggs),CONTAINS(Breakfast)->MARK(EggsForBreakfast)};
```

You can use different language elements for engineering these patterns, like sequential rules with wildcards, inlined rules and various conditions as in the example above. The best solution depends on the actual use case, e.g., are we including structures like chunks or syntax trees?

*DISCLAIMER: I am a developer of UIMA Ruta*